# Block Mouse Scroll inside DIV

Tags: javascript, php, scroll, mouseevent

How to block mouse scroll in a div with `id="slider-'.$question_id.'"`

So basically if you put mouse over that div, click it you will not be able to scroll using mouse scroll.

```
<div id="slider-'.$question_id.'"> CONTENT </div>
```

I am only looking for solution with **JavaScript**

I have code below, but this is blocking whole page:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.onmousewheel = function(){ stopWheel(); } /* IE7, IE8 */
if(document.addEventListener){ /* Chrome, Safari, Firefox */
    document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', stopWheel, false);
}

function stopWheel(e){
    if(!e){ e = window.event; } /* IE7, IE8, Chrome, Safari */
    if(e.preventDefault) { e.preventDefault(); } /* Chrome, Safari, Firefox */
    e.returnValue = false; /* IE7, IE8 */
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are single quotes allowed in attribute names?

Comment: "slider-'.$question_id.'" something feels wrong here... copy paste from php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use event.target to identify if the scrolling element is the one you want to affect:

```
function stopWheel(e){
    if (e.target.id === "slider-'.$question_id.'") {
        if(!e){ e = window.event; } /* IE7, IE8, Chrome, Safari */
        if(e.preventDefault) { e.preventDefault(); } /* Chrome, Safari, Firefox */
        e.returnValue = false; /* IE7, IE8 */
    }
}
```

Plus you need to provide the event in the first call:

```
document.onmousewheel = function (e) {
    stopWheel(e);
} /* IE7, IE8 */
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Da3L3/

Comment: great, how do I apply this on div tag ?

Comment: which element I run onLoad ?

Comment: Nothing, just click run and try to scroll on the bottom right

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the div so you can try something like :

```
document.getElementByID("slider-'.$question_id.'").onmousewheel = function(){ stopWheel(); } /* IE7, IE8 */
if(document.getElementByID("slider-'.$question_id.'").addEventListener){ /* Chrome, Safari, Firefox */
    document.getElementByID("slider-'.$question_id.'").addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', stopWheel, false);
}
```

Hope i help

Comment: it's look to work for me on this fiddle jsfiddle.net/833qE (i test with chrome)

Comment: this is stop scrolling page when in DIV, I need stop scrolling inside DIV :)