# Enable only click and hover on SVG element

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, mouseevent

I have an SVG element in my page which hinders the general scrolling of the page in mobile. I was able to solve the issue using:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

However, I require the `hover` and `click` events to fire. Is there any way to disable all mouse events except `hover` and `click`?

Comment: can you share enough code that shows your issue so we can help ... pointer-events doesn't filter such event and not another. ... scrolling ? is that the first issue ? what about obverflow ?

Comment: I tried `overflow: hidden` but it didn't work. I'll share a plunkr link in a while.

Comment: if it is just scrolling, maybe the idea would be to use javascript and catch/kill scroll events before it fires scrolling :). I guess your question deserve to be rephrased then css tag removed ;)

Comment: Would that work? I will need to scrolling to be enabled on the body but not on the svg. Let me try that.

Comment: would this be it ? if so, probably a duplicate   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23389689/block-mouse-scroll-inside-div

Comment: Let me try that. Thanks for the efforts :)

Comment: Could you just set what ever events you dont want to use to null ? For example, .on('dblclick',null) etc ?